# React: How to seperate admin-dashboard and mainsite?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, single-page-application

I am developing a used car sales website. I want to have an admin panel where the admin enters the cars and photos. I also want to have a seperate site with a different look a feel for customers to search for cars.

I would like to make sure that the styles for both sites don't collide because I want both sites in the same react project. So far my solution is to use nested routes as shown below. if the route is /admin then the admin application is loaded, otherwise if it's / then i load the normal site.

```
import MainSite from "app/modules/mainsite/main";
import AdminSite from "app/modules/admin/main";

const baseHref = document
  .querySelector("base")
  .getAttribute("href")
  .replace(/\/$/, "");

export interface IAppProps extends StateProps, DispatchProps {}

export class App extends React.Component<IAppProps> {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getSession();
    this.props.getProfile();
  }

  render() {
    const paddingTop = "60px";
    return (
      <Router basename={baseHref}>
        <ErrorBoundary>
          <div className="view-routes">
            <Switch>
              <ErrorBoundaryRoute exact path="/" component={MainSite} />
              <ErrorBoundaryRoute exact path="/admin" component={AdminSite} />
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </ErrorBoundary>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

`AdminSite` will then contain nested routes for each of its components. This will also be true for `MainSite`. I'm open to suggestions. Is there a better way that I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

That is a fine way to do that. Though make sure to handle authentication for the admin page.